# $\lim_{z \to a} f(z) = L$ iff $\forall z_n s.t. z_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty, f(z_n) \to L$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to prove this lemma, but I'm stumped. This lemma is presented first thing after the definition of a limit for complex functions, so I don't have previous results to use here.

The left hand statement translates to:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $0 < |z - a| < \delta \implies |f(z) - L| < \varepsilon$

Right hand statement translates to:

$\forall (z_n)$ s.t. $z_n \to a$, $f(z_n) \to L$

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is true for any metric space.

$\implies$ is quite immediate.

For the reverse implication you can proceed by contradiction. If $\lim\limits_{z \to a} f(z) = L$ doesn't hold, you can find $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, it exists $z_\delta$ such that $0 < \vert z_\delta - a\vert < \delta$ and $\vert f(z_\delta) - f(a) \vert \ge \epsilon_0$. As this is valid for all $\delta >0$, take $\delta_n = 1/n$ with $n \in \mathbb N$ to obtain a sequence contradicting the sequence convergence assumption.

Comment: Forgive me, but I do not see how it is immediate. Could you please elaborate?